# How can i change PCF (pcf-scripts) default port?

Tags: dynamics-crm, pcf, pcfdev

When using PowerApps Component Framework (PCF) scripts npm library, how can i change the default 8181 port?

--port "8282"
I've also tried to use devServer: { port: 8282} on webpack.config

There's no documentation about that on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/component-framework/create-custom-controls-using-pcf or https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcf-scripts